# how to make bot to enter a website automatically?

Tags: automation, bots

for example I have 10 username and password in a text file, 
I want a software or bot that go to a website, enter the website and hit a button and then go to other username.

Comment: There's about a million different ways to do this, ranging from a python script to using selenium.  You're going to need to narrow it down...a lot.

Comment: I don't know any coding language, it would be good, if you show me software

Answer (score 0):

For example you could use `wget`. Most Linux distro's do have this tool.
Try:

```
wget --user username --password secret http://example.com/
```